# Make Brackets open maximised?

Tags: 14.04, .desktop, wmctrl, maximized, adobe-brackets

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 with brackets installed (btw, does brackets work on Ubuntu 17? Coz when I checked with 16 it didn't? But anyway...)

**The problem**

When I open Brackets it always comes up in this tiny window which is no good fit working with.

**What I want**

I wish... I wish that Brackets would open in a maximised window... Unfortunately, the has been [this bug](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/7174) around for like 3 years and it doesn't look like anyone is willing to do anything about it... I would therefore like to propose a workaround.

**Proposed (theoretical) workaround**

I found that this command

```
wmctrl -r Brackets -b add,maximized_horz,maximized_vert
```

will maximise the window if Brackets is open. So now I need to find a way to run it immediately after Brackets opens.

I have tried to put the command into the `brackets.desktop` file, but it doesn't seem to work...

```
Exec=/opt/brackets/brackets %U && wmctrl -r Brackets -b add,maximized_horz,maximized_vert
```

I've also tried with a semicolon instead of `&&` but it also doesn't work. I have a feeling that it's because I can't put 2 commands like that in a desktop file, since it will only run the second one after it finished with the first one, which would be after the program is closed... Am I right? I'm just making this up...

I've also tried to do this by setting the maximised settings in the desktop file (can't remember exactly what I did, it was a long time ago).

So, is there any way for me to achieve the desired outcome here?

Comment: You could try launching brackets via a script that launches brackets as usual and then executes your wmctrl command. Seems logical.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that, but how can I make it run my command only after it opens brackets?

Comment: One way would be to add an appropriate sleep timer in the script between the `brackets` and `wmctrl` command.. See `man sleep` There are likely other ways to accomplish this as well

Comment: I've never really liked using sleep timers... There's no guarantee that the program will be ready for it to run when is set... Or it could take much longer than necessary.... It's there no more orthodox method?

Comment: I have no doubt there are other methods, sadly I'm unable to test as I don't have brackets installed. It would seem logical that you could check the process stack for the pid (the existence of which would seem to indicate that the process had launched), but again, I can't test it or I'd write you an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll try out this stuff tomorrow perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

So I made a simple script that will do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
/opt/brackets/brackets &
sleep 1
wmctrl -r Brackets -b add,maximized_horz,maximized_vert
```

The `sleep 1` is just to give the window time to open so it is recognised by the following command which will maximise it.

Then I just changed the `Exec=/opt/brackets/brackets` line in the `Brackets.desktop` file to `Exec=/path/to/script.sh`.

Remember to make the script executable with

```
sudo chmod +x /path/to/script.sh
```